# Are compact cameras with USB-C available?

Tags: usb

I am trying not to buy any more consumer electronics devices with micro-USB connectors.  The USB Type C connector standard was finalized in 2014 so I am hoping to see cameras with USB-C in time for the 2016 holiday season.  Are there any?

If there aren't any yet, when should they be available?  How long is the typical lag time for new technologies to be included in cameras?

For a compact camera, USB-C charging would be an excellent feature.

Camera review sites seem to not mention the type of USB port on a camera, and my Google searches are not finding anything.

Comment: Considering how long it took for USB3 connections to start showing up on cameras after they started appearing on computers and other devices I wouldn't hold my breath waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but at the moment they're all phones.

The standard was finalised in 2014, but we only started to see it in use in phones last year, and it's still not ubiquitous. Camera manufacturers have a slower release cycle than phones (where the pace of development is very aggressive).

Its likely to appear in many more small devices after it becomes commonplace in phones, but for now it's likely that camera manufacturers will play it safe.

Answer (score 1):

There is one camera, though I'm not sure whether it's available for sale yet; I recall seeing a sneak peak of the Olympus E-M1 Mk II (probably on DigitalRev TV), which featured a USB-C connector. It might be worth checking out, though it certainly won't be cheap.

- A *very* pleased user of the E-M10 Mk 1, the same line's most low-end model.